# Code not working

Tags: arduino-mega

[image]Basically, it's an Arduino project in which I am stuck. I using inputs as two sensors and LED as output, for further details and concept video had been attached. I did the wiring and everything correctly but there is something wrong with the code which I couldn't figure out. Here is the code.

I had attached a video for proper understanding.

https://youtu.be/ZQg_xbGQNE0

```
const int s1 = 22;     // sensor one
const int s2 =  23;      // sensor two
int pot_pin = A0;
int list[15] = {2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 44, 45, 46}; //leds pin
//if u want change the time delay
int timer = 1000;

bool flag1 = false;
void setup() {
  // initialize the pushbutton pin as an input:
  pinMode(s1, INPUT);
  pinMode(s1, INPUT);
  // initialize the LED pin as an output:
  for (int thisPin = 0; thisPin < 15; thisPin++) {
    pinMode(list[thisPin], OUTPUT);
  }


}

void loop() {
  // read the state of the pushbutton value:
  int output = analogRead(pot_pin);
  int led_value = map(output, 0, 1023, 0, 255);

  if (digitalRead(s1) == HIGH) {
    for (int thisPin = 0; thisPin < 15; thisPin++) {
      if (digitalRead(s2) == LOW) {
        // turn the pin on:
        analogWrite(list[thisPin], led_value);
        //digitalWrite(thisPin, HIGH);
        delay(timer);
      }
      else {

        for (int de = 14; thisPin < 15; thisPin++) {
          analogWrite(list[thisPin], led_value);
          analogWrite(list[de], led_value);
          //digitalWrite(thisPin, HIGH);
          //digitalWrite(de, HIGH);
          delay(timer);
          de--;
        }

      }
    }
    flag1 = true;

  }
  if (digitalRead(s2) == HIGH and flag1 == true) {
    for (int thisPin = 0; thisPin < 15; thisPin++) {
      if (digitalRead(s1) == LOW) {

        digitalWrite(list[thisPin], LOW);
        delay(timer);
      }
      else {
        for (int de = 14; thisPin < 15; thisPin++) {
          digitalWrite(list[thisPin], LOW);
          digitalWrite(list[de], LOW);
          delay(timer);
          de--;
        }

      }

    }
    flag1 = false;
  }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is now working? Show us schema of your hardware. Are you using ArduinoUno?

Comment: Arduino mega, the second case is not working, you can have a look into the video.

Comment: Is the video what it should be? Is the sketch only for CASE-2?

Comment: Please edit your post and replace the title with one that gives more information about the question being asked.

Comment: the code is for all the cases

Comment: how do you know that it is not working? .... you said nothing about what you expect to happen ..... you also said nothing about what actually happens

Comment: You might have seen the video, you may see different cases been mentioned now according to me the code I made is ok, now the second case according to video is not working further all the cases are working, now I myself not getting that why it is not working accordingly, and i what i want is all the cases should run in a single program.